# Си, предотвратить дублирование кода парсера

Tags: c, парсер, шаблоны-проектирования, рефакторинг

Разрабатываю парсер одного DSL на Си. Ранее на вход подавались только файлы, но возникла нужда обрабатывать текст в виде `char*`. Можно ли это сделать просто и адекватно?

Сейчас код упрощённо выглядит так:

```c
void parseFile(const char* filename) {
    // Инициализация привязанная к способу чтения
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    // Проверка на наличие файла и т.п

    // Инициализация независимая от способа чтения
    char *line = NULL;
    XYZ = ...;

    // Часть цикла привязанная к способу чтения
    while ((line = getLineFromFile(fp))) {
        // Часть цикла независимая от способа чтения
        XYZ = parseLine(line, XYZ);
    }

    // Итоговая часть привязанная к способу чтения
    close(fp);

    // Итоговая часть независимая от способа чтения
    free(line);
    free(XY);
    return Z;
}
```

Видно, что в начале и конце функции, а также внутри цикла есть куски кода, обрабатывающие конкретный способ чтения, и куски, связанные чисто с парсингом. Я вижу такие варианты действий:

1. По-простому можно просто скопировать функцию и заменить части по работе с файлами на разбор `char*`, но это будет дублированием кода и необходимостью поддерживать одно и то же в двух местах.
2. Можно сделать немного умнее, с инкапсуляцией – вынести переменные для парсинга в структуру и написать функции для работы с ней (init/process/finish). Но это как-то излишне громоздко, на мой взгляд, всего лишь 2 однотипных применения.

Есть ли более лаконичный способ, паттерн без дублирования кода?

---

**Update**

3. Есть ещё вариант свести один вариант к другому. Я считал его слишком ресурсоёмким, но [Mike предложил использовать `mmap`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1051784/%D0%A1%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0#comment1797209_1051784), который поможет в данной задаче. Однако что в других случаях, есть ли альтернативы этим 3м вариантам?

Comment: Сделать одну функцию, работающую с `char *`. При работе с файлами, отражать их на память с помощью `mmap()` и далее они будут не отличимы от `char *` (и работать будут быстрее и памяти меньше использовать, чем через fread)

Comment: @Mike у меня была идея запихнуть весь файл в память и работать уже только со строкой... Но не будет ли это большим оверхедом если файл большой?

Comment: Поэтому я и предлагаю использовать mmap, а не читать файл. При использовании этой функции ядро создает сегмент виртуальной памяти, отраженной на файл. Файл при этом сразу не читается, а читается страницами, по мере обращения программы. При недостатке памяти старые страницы удаляются. Память процесса не используется вообще, в адресное пространство процесса ядро отображает файловые буфера в которые диск отдал запрошенное, что убирает копирование из буфера ядра в память процесса. Для самой программы это все выглядит как  кусок обычной памяти, возможно большего размера чем есть в системе ОЗУ

Comment: @Mike Спасибо! Уже прочёл об этом и примеры, вроде это то, что надо. Можете оформить ответом, я приму `:)` Хотя это отходит от изначального вопроса, на который тоже было бы интересно получить ответ.

Comment: я в своём древнем парсере json, например, пользовал #define вовсю: https://github.com/Sheridan/mon/blob/master/trunk/application/libraryes/base/parcer/parcer-helper.h

Comment: @Sheridan Вы даже не представляете, какую магию с макросами я там устроил, полноценные шаблонные структуры данных с кучей прибомбасов, да отслеживание утечек памяти  Но не уверен, что в данной задаче макросы сделают решение лучшее, чем описанные в вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно использовать указатели на функции.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void parse(char*(*getLineFn)(), void(*disposeFn)(char*)) {
    char* data = getLineFn();

    /* Тут типа парсер обрабатывает строку */
    printf("Parser input:");
    printf(data);
    printf("\n");

    disposeFn(data);
}

char* getConstLine() {
    return "hi!";
}

void noNeedToDispose(char* str) {
    /* Если в getLineFn был malloc, тут будет free, и т.д. */
}

int main(void) {
    parse(&getConstLine, &noNeedToDispose);
    return 0;
}
```

Надо работать с файлом? Подсовываете функции, читающие из файла. Из памяти - другие функции.

В том виде, в котором я написал выше, один большой минус - любое состояние придётся хранить в глобальных переменных, т.к. функции С это не замыкания, и даже не делегаты. Но ничего страшного, можно добавить параметр `void* context`, и передавать через него состояние между функциями.

Comment: Переменные, как я писал, присутствуют и хранить их надо, тогда нужна ещё структура... В итоге, Ваше решение – этот тот же мой 3-й способ, только выносится код по считыванию, а не парсингу, что увеличивает число функций и структур вдвое `:)`

Comment: Может, функций будет больше. Но имхо в первую очередь важна архитектура, читаемость и логичность кода, а плюс/минус пара функций - дело второе. Что, по-вашему, логичнее: чтобы парсер, условно, говорил: так, чуваки, дайте-ка мне строчку, неважно откуда, я её обработаю! или чтобы некая процедура, работающая с файлом, подсовывала строчку парсеру, и независимо другая процедура, работающая с памятью, подсовывала строчку парсеру... Ну, ваш парсер, ваш выбор :)

Comment: @AivanF. и да, раз в посте вы упоминали паттерны, то что я предложил - ближе всего к Inversion of Control.